# Creating a Range based on two Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas, range

I have the following dataset

```
Out[121]: 
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

and would like to generate a column with the range of the numbers from a and b. So:

```
Out[128]: 
   a  b      range
0  1  3  [1, 2, 3]
1  2  4  [2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension for this. You might find this more efficient than `pd.DataFrame.apply`.

```
df['range'] = [list(range(i, j+1)) for i, j in df.values]
```

Result:

```
   a  b      range
0  1  3  [1, 2, 3]
1  2  4  [2, 3, 4]
```

This works because:

- You can assign a series directly via a list.
- `df.values` returns the `numpy` array representation of the dataframe which, when you iterate, returns the contents of each row.
- If you have more columns, simply use `df[['a', 'b']].values`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention `range`

```
df['range']=df.apply(lambda x : list(range(x['a'],x['b']+1)),1)
df
Out[242]: 
   a  b      range
0  1  3  [1, 2, 3]
1  2  4  [2, 3, 4]
```

Notice , you can using this one to speed up (replace `apply`)

```
list(map(lambda x : list(range(x[0],x[1]+1)),df[['a','b']].values))
Out[248]: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
```